# How can you encrypt a string in javascript and decrypt it in php?

Tags: javascript, php, security, encryption

I found several questions on Stackoverflow regarding javascript encryption, but I couldn't find one for encryption in javascript and decryption in php. What api would be best?

I'm looking to make added security for my web application. I want some variables to be encrypted on the client and then decrypted on the server (with php).

Thank you!

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Moreover you'll need to obfuscate your JAVASCRIPT since it can be accessed using firebug.

Comment: If you want it to be secure against the network, your Javascript needs to be rolled into a browser extension. (At this point, I would recommend using libsodium.) If you want it to be secure against a savvy end user, good luck.